# replace dataset values r by another indexed values

Tags: r, dataset

I have the following datasets

```
head(data)

  from  to
1    1   2
2    2   3
3    2  17
4    3   4
5    4   5
6    4 855
```

And I have this dataset

```
 > head(names)
           V1
1    Greenock
2     Glasgow
3     Preston
4  Birmingham
5 Southampton
6          Le
```

now what I want is very easy:

```
head(data)

         from            to
1    Greenock     Glasgow
2    Glasgow      Preston
3    Glasgow      17 (you got the point)
4    Preston      Birmingham
5    Birmingham   Southampton
6    Birmingham   855
```

I tried this old fashion for-loop but

```
> for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
+ data$from[i] <- names$V1[data$from]
+ data$to[i] <- names$V1[data$to]
+ }
```

1. It doesn't work well
2. I know it's not great job

Any ideas?

Comment: mutate(a = replace(a, id, b[id]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R's `factor`s were made for this type of data. It keeps the data as numbers, but add human readable `level`s.

I would just convert the `from` and `to` columns to `factor`s:

```
data$from <- factor(data$from)
data$to <- factor(data$to)
```

and then change the labels of the levels:

```
levels(data$from) <- names$V1
levels(data$to) <- names$V1
```

The above code works for me:

```
data <- data.frame(
 from = 1:10,
 to = seq(from=10, to=1, by=-1))

names <- data.frame(
  V1 = c('a','b','c','d','e', 'f','g','h','i','j'))

data$from <- factor(data$from)
data$to <- factor(data$to)

levels(data$from) <- names$V1
levels(data$to) <- names$V1

print(data)
```

Results in:

```
   from to
1     a  j
2     b  i
3     c  h
4     d  g
5     e  f
6     f  e
7     g  d
8     h  c
9     i  b
10    j  a
```

This answer does assume that you have a label for every single number. If this is not the case, it often means that something is wrong with the data and that you want an error to be thrown. You should assert that `max(data[,c('to','from')]) <= nrow(names)` (not tested) using either `stopifnot` or (better) `assert_that` from Hadley's assertthat package.

If you do not want to make this assumption, you should use @RichardScriven's answer.

Comment: What about the second column?

Comment: @RichardScriven just added

Comment: Try using the data from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using some logical subsetting and `replace()`.

```
dlg <- data <= nrow(names)
replace(data, dlg, as.character(names$V1)[unlist(data)][dlg])
#         from          to
# 1   Greenock     Glasgow
# 2    Glasgow     Preston
# 3    Glasgow          17
# 4    Preston  Birmingham
# 5 Birmingham Southampton
# 6 Birmingham         855
```

By the way, `data` and `names` are both names of important base functions, so you might want to rename your data sets.